# connlimit counters start over after iptables restored

Tags: iptables, firewall, ip-conntrack

I have a connlimit rule in iptables that allow only 5 connection to port 80.

> iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit
>   --connlimit-above 5 --connlimit-saddr -j DROP

This rule works fine till I restore iptables. After restore rules, connlimit counters start over and clients/attackers can open 5 more connection.

Is it possible to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Use `iptables-save` or `iptables-resotre` with `-c` option to include bytes and **counters**.

> http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-save-restore-rules.html

Comment: the counter is just how many times the rule has hit, not the number of connections per tuple of IP addresses and per rule. I presume the ones who have upvoted didn't try, because it doesn't work.